# how to display and update data in textbox of asp.net by using stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net

i want to update user information .so first i want when user click on update button than all the field display with their values in text box so that user can able to edit his profile.
i got an error :Procedure or function 'updatefill' expects parameter '@email', which was not supplied.
please help me out from this error...
Thank you.

```
public partial class updateuser : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnstr"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataTable dt;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    string str1="";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        {
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("updatefill", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds,"registr");
            fname.Text = ds.Tables["registr"].Rows[0]["fname"].ToString();
            lname.Text = ds.Tables["registr"].Rows[0]["lname"].ToString();
            uid.Text = ds.Tables["registr"].Rows[0]["email"].ToString();
            pwd.Text = ds.Tables["registr"].Rows[0]["password"].ToString();
            pwd1.Text = ds.Tables["registr"].Rows[0]["confirmpassword"].ToString();
            mbl.Text = ds.Tables["registr"].Rows[0]["mobile"].ToString();
            con.Close();




        }
    }
    protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (RadioButton1.Checked)
        {
            str1 = "Male";
        }
        else if (RadioButton2.Checked)
        {
            str1 = "Female";
        }
        else
        {
            str1 = "please select gender";
        }
    }
    protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("update_user_details", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fname.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lname.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = uid.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@mobile", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = mbl.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pwd.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@confirmpassword", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pwd1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@gender", str1); 
        dt = new DataTable();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        int s = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0]);
        if (s == 1)
        {

            errmsg.Text = "Update Successfull";
            Response.Redirect("userhome.aspx");

        }
        else
        {
            errmsg.Text = "Update Faild";

            con.Close();
}


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updatefill]
@email varchar(50) 

AS
BEGIN

    select * from registr where email=@email
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the Reader:

```
        String connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB1"].ConnectionString;
        String cmdStr = "SELECT [col2],[col3] FROM [Table1] WHERE [col1]=@col1;";
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(("updatefill", con);
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = C0mmandType.StoredProcedure;
                    conn.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            fname.Text = rdr[0];
                            lname.Text = rdr[1]
                            uid.Text = rdr[2]
                            pwd.Text = rdr[3]
                            pwd1.Text = rdr[4];
                            mbl.Text = rdr[5];
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    conn.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Thank You so much sir...but i solved it in the same way as i code...Thank you for your support.